# Sharing files over an intra-network

Tags: networking

Let us say there are three nodes, node A, node B and node C connected with each other (intra-network). There are some files stored in node C. Node A wants to view a file which is stored in node C. Assume that node A uses some protocol X to communicate to node C and vice versa. The question is when the file is being sent from node C to node A, does the file gets locally saved in node A or it is present in some temporary buffer of node A. In a nut-shell where is the file present in node A when I view the file from node A.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

let's take webserver as an example:

1. Node  A is the client, Node C is the server in this case
2. ues a broswer in Node  A to access Node  C
3. when you just  simply  view  the  file  list, the  server only  need to send the  brife information of  the files(name ,size  .etc )
4. if  you download  the  file , it would finally  be  stored in the location you  assigned.
5. if  you  directly open  the  file with  some other app, the  file  would be  stored in the  Temp File Folder of you  Browser.